# How to copy the text formats in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm writing a blog and I want to copy one paragraph's formatting to the next paragraph. The HTML section says the both paras are in the same format but Visually it doesn't any idea why ? 
p.s - I tried the HTML section it didn't work

Comment: please add a screenshot of your wysiwyg editor text tab selected. Wit little info it is hard to say anything

Comment: If you compared both HTMLs and don't see any difference. Probably that content gets put on the page (different loop or something) adding a different wrapper or class with different styles ...